# How do display MongoDB aggregation pipeline results on the front end of a web application?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express

I have a web application that utilizes MongoDB pipeline aggregation in a controller file. I can run a GET request in Postman, and it returns the expected results. How would I go about displaying the same results on the front of my application? I am using Pug templates and express, and would typically make the database information available to the front end using code like this in my view controller:

```
    exports.addReview = async (req, res, next) => {
      const ships = await Ship.find();
    
      res.status(200).render('addReview', {
        title: `Add Your Review`,
        ships,
      });
    };
```

Is there a similar approach to the above for including pipeline aggregation data? This is the aggregation code:

```
exports.getHighestRatings = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const highestRatings = await Review.aggregate([
    {
      $sort: { rating: -1 },
    },
  ]);

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Success',
    data: {
      highestRatings,
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes".

Aggregation data acts the same as any other data you get from MongoDB. All that is different is that `aggregation` is much more sophisticated method than the `find()` method you used above, so the JSON will be organized a little differently.

Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(highestRatings))` to see how it's organized.

A couple comments on your code:

1. You don't need to use aggregation to sort. You can just piggie-back `sort()` on the end of a `find()` method, and it will do it for you, like this:

   Review.find().sort({ rating: -1 })
2. In your second example you're sending the code back using `res.status(200).json()` but if you want it to render on the front end, you probably want to use the same `.render()` method that you used in the first example, like this:

   res.status(200).render()

I hope this helps. If I misunderstood the question, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a variable sent by express in your front pug view by using :

```
ships
```

Since it will be an array, you should loop on it with :

```
each ship in ships
```

And access it with

```
ship
```